# Difficulty understanding nested expressions in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, let

Here's a function that asks a number and returns the value if its type is indeed a number and else executes the function again:

```
(defun ask-number ()
  (format t "Please enter a number.~%")
  (let ((val (read)))
    (if (numberp val)
        val
        (ask-number))))
```

I understand that after the value is read, it is labelled as `val` and the whole `((val (read)))` is an argument of `let`. What I don't understand is, why the if-statement is nested within `let`. I would have assumed that the program should be something like this:

```
(defun ask-number ()
  (format t "Please enter a number.~%")
  (let ((val (read))))
  (if (numberp val)
      val
      (ask-number)))
```

which leads to an error. I am not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the `if` is inside the `let` is that the `val` you've created with the `let` is only valid within the `let`; once you exit the `let`, `val` doesn't exist any more.

`let` is syntactic sugar for creating and instantly calling a `lambda` expression, so your `let` expression is basically the same as:

```
((lambda (val)
   (if (numberp val)
       val
       (ask-number)))
 (read))
```

Comment: As an analogy with a C program, you couldn't do `void foo(int x) { x = 3; } printf("%d", x);"  The variable is no longer in scope.  `let` introduces scope, just like a function definition does.  You *could* do this, though:  `(let ((val nil)) (set! val (read)) (if (numberp val) ...))`.